# Ruby WriteExcel number_format with the Euro Sign

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet

I am trying to add the Euro Sign in a number format like so:

```
workbook.add_format(:num_format => "[$€-2] #,##0.00")
```

It errors with:

```
'store_num_format': Uneven number of bytes in Unicode font name
```

The document font is `Arial` by default.
I can change it to a Dollar Sign and it works.

```
workbook.add_format(:num_format => "[$$-409]#,##0.00")
```

Anyone had a problem getting the Euro Sign to show up in WriteExcel?

Comment: This issue is fixed now. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That syntax should work, (it works in the Perl module that it is ported from), however there is a bug in one of the sub-classes.

I'll report it.

In the meantime you could try the [write_xlsx](http://rubygems.org/gems/write_xlsx) gem which is by the same author and which is an API compatible replacement for writeexcel, except that it targets the XLSX file format.

Update 1: [Issue reported](https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel/issues/19).

Update 2: [Issue fixed](https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel/issues/19).

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but you really ought to consider checking out [axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx). It handles string encoding properly and provides a much nicer API in general.

Example:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'axlsx'
p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook

euro = wb.styles.add_style(:format_code => "[$€-2] #,##0.00")

wb.add_worksheet do |sheet|
  100.times do |i|
    sheet.add_row [100*i], :style => euro
  end
end

p.serialize '/tmp/test.xlsx'
```